# playaudio() in Octave

Tags: octave

I'm trying to run the following line to play a signal:

```
>> playaudio(sig);
```

But the terminal returns:

```
>> sh: cannot create /dev/dsp: Permission denied
```

How can I correct this? Thanks

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting octave with superuser rights

```
sudo octave
```

Then try to play it again

```
>> playaudio(signal)
```

If this doesn't work, try installing the package named octave-audio (might also need to install a package named sox).

Answer (score 0):

`playaudio` was deprecated in Octave 4.0 and will be removed in 4.4. Use `audioplayer` instead.